# Best practice to keep a NTFS partition constantly mounted?

Tags: 11.04, mount, dual-boot, ntfs

Hey all, I Dual-boot using a NTFS partition to house shared docs and some program files between Windows and Ubuntu. When this extra media partition isn't mounted automatically at startup it causes usability problems. In the past I have installed and used "NTFS Configuration Tool" to achieve this. Since I just cleanly installed ubuntu 11.04, I thought it would be fitting to ask if anyone has found a better method?

Answer (score 2):

From what i can gleen from the question, you should add the device to the `fstab` for auto mounting at boot time. I've got several dual boot pc's on my network and they auto-mount the NTFS partition without any usability issues.

My personal mount line in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/large ntfs user 0 0
```

if you dont want it to auto-mount at boot, you can always add the `noauto` flag

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/large noauto,ntfs user 0 0
```

With this particular line, any user can mount/unmount the volume.

Comment: Is there a newbie GUI tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways, but my recommendation is... make required no folders in `/mnt`

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/C /mnt/D
```

Then, check your partition list using

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

note the enteries from the list. Now open `/etc/fstab` so that you can write into it

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Now add entries in the following manner

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/C ntfs-3g rw,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000 0 0  
/dev/sda3 /mnt/D ntfs-3g rw,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000 0 0
```

**Note**:
`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` will be replaced with entries you get from `fdisk -l`, and
 `/mnt/C` and `/mnt/D` shall replace with your directories you made using `mkdir`.
To understand what `fmask and dmask` do please visit [Fmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fmask)

Comment: Good answer, but for completeness you should also include what your file masks and directory masks are doing, and why they are important.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PYDSM (Storage device manager) for quite some time.  Its simple and straightforward.  I'm pretty sure you can get it in the Software Center

Comment: Warning for folks reading this for later versions: this is no longer supported, and this and other versions can be dangerous. Manual is best in this situation. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Systemwide_Mounts