# Automatic NTFS Partition Mount on Startup

Tags: startup, ntfs, automount

I have been looking through other answers on this site but I can't seem to get automatic mount of a partition quite right. I want the partition to automount on startup, and the partition is NTFS formatted.

When I run `sudo blkid` this is the readout for the particular partition:

```
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Shared" UUID="8255" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is actually quite simpel, (a.o.) her you can find how to do that: http://askubuntu.com/a/525516/72216 (in the format `/dev/sda6 /mountpoint ntfs auto`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to keep a NTFS partition constantly mounted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43998/best-practice-to-keep-a-ntfs-partition-constantly-mounted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Answer (score 6):

Into disk software. select partition that you want do this. Click its setting, select edit mount options, "Mount at startup":

[image: Mount at startup]