# What process occurs when I access another partition from "other locations" in nautilus?

Tags: partitioning

I have some data in a 400 GB nfts partition that I seed from, but if I try to open qbittorrent before opening the partition in nautilus I get errors, so I have been manually opening it on each boot. What is this process and how can I do it from command line (and therefore make it happen automatically from startup?). Is this Quora thread (https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-mount-a-partition-on-Ubuntu) talking about my question? It seems to be, but I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/598036/automatic-ntfs-partition-mount-on-startup

Comment: this is a duplicate, don't know how I ddin't see those threads when searching, apologies for the hassles